# How to properly import and configure .csv table in sqlite3

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

I'm extremely new to django and wanted to figure out how to properly import .csv files into tables in sqlite3 and configure my 'home' section to obtain information from that specific table.

Here's what I've done so far..

I've imported a .csv file into a tabled called "csv_master_data", and I want to configure my "home" directory to be able to retrieve data from that particular table
[image]

Next after watching some tutorials I didn't completely understand how to setup models.py in order to communicate with that table, so far it seems like people are showing how to create a brand new section in the database, and I want to be able to retrieve the information from the db, again sorry for the newbie question, I'm completely new to databases and django as a whole.

[image]

If you notice in my models.py, is this how it would be done? please disregard the

```
class Schools(models.Model)
```

and I know the names for the rows are incorrect, I just want to know if I rename them using the names within the rows of my csv_master_data would they properly communicate, and how I would be able to migrate them properly to understand that, I want to obtain information from that particular table.

If i'm looking at this the wrong way if someone can explain or if anyone has any tutorial recommendations to look at on how to be able to set this up properly I would really appreciate it!

Update:
from reading a few articles I was told to do the following command to kind of see a pre-generated model.py to use (I think), here is the result in the following picture..

The following command gave the result below:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

[image]

(**Note:** I changed the csv_master_data, table name to "HomeDb", just wanted to clarify to not cause confusion.)

Would I simply copy paste that inside my models.py in my "home" directory and i'm good to go, or am I missing something here, kind of scared to really continue for the sake of not destroying my project. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table already in your database, then `python manage.py inspectdb` will generate the models for you. But if you want to create new models you can write your models and then run migrations for it. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/).

Now if you want to insert some data to these models via csv, you can export the data easily using [django-import-export](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export).

I hope you have gone through this [basic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/) intro to django.

Now regarding your scenario , I would suggest you to first create proper database architecture and then create your models. After that you can export the required data from the csv.

Hope it helps.